# PHPUnit not running all the tests from a directory

Tags: php, phpunit

I try to run all the tests from a specific test directory as follow:

```
|-- Service
|   |-- Cla
|       |-- ClaService.php
|       |-- SubscriptionService.php
|-- Tests
    |-- Service
        |-- Cla
            |-- ClaServiceTest.php : tests for ClaService.php
            |-- SubscriptionServiceTest.php : tests for SubscriptionService.php
```

So I try to run `bin/phpunit --coverage-text Tests/Service/Cla/` which not run any tests from SubscriptionServiceTest.php, do you have any idea why ?

Here's an extract of the `phpunit.xml` :

```xml
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
        <directory>./Tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>

<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory>./</directory>
        <exclude>
            <directory>./Resources</directory>
            <directory>./Tests</directory>
            <directory>./vendor</directory>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

Comment: `<directory>./Tests</directory>` is in your excludes, is that right?

Comment: can you share the composer.json files and one of the test class?

Comment: @apokryfos Yes, it prevents to run tests on tests

Comment: No @apokryfos is right, that will prevent your tests being run, the test suite is in ./Tests which are defined in testsuites.

Comment: When I run `bin/phpunit --coverage-text Tests/Service/Cla/SubscriptionServiceTest.php` it runs tests correctly

Comment: @LawrenceCherone But I tried without the `<directory>./Tests</directory>` in `<exclude>` it didn't change anything

Comment: So when you run just `phpunit` in the same directory as phpunit.xml whats happening? Also check your namespacing is correct.

Comment: I checked the namespaces of tests and classes it's correct (`Lmd\UserBundle\Service\Cla` and `Lmd\UserBundle\Tests\Service\Cla`).

Comment: I'm just finding it very odd to have a testuite on a directory that you then exclude from tests. I'm not sure if that would cause a problem.

Comment: @apokryfos I agree but it doesn't seems to cause the real problem

Comment: `<filter>` is only useful for test coverage: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.whitelisting-files

Comment: Try running `/bin/phpunit --filter <namespace>\SubscriptionServiceTest::testSomething` and see if phpunit can pick it up like that usually it should collect everything and then match the filter but if it can't find those tests at all then it wont run anything

Comment: @LawrenceCherone when i run phpunit with --debug this is my output :

`
Starting test 'Lmd\UserBundle\Tests\Service\Cla\ClaServiceTest::testGetUserServicesIdWithError'.
Starting test 'Lmd\UserBundle\Tests\Service\Cla\ClaServiceTest::testGetUserServicesIdOnSuccessWithDefault'.
Starting test 'Lmd\UserBundle\Tests\Service\Cla\ClaServiceTest::testGetUserServicesIdOnSuccessWithoutDefault'.
Starting test 'Lmd\UserBundle\Tests\Service\EncryptionServiceTest::testConstructThrowExceptionWhenMandatoryConfigNotGiven'.
`
See,the SubscriptionServiceTest not here :-/

Comment: @apokryfos **No tests executed!**

Comment: Note that ClaServiceTest use some public static methods from SubscriptionServiceTest

Comment: Perhaps there's clues inside the source code, perhaps share the namespace and class skeleton (actual test contents are probably not important)

Comment: @apokryfos and @LawrenceCherone I get it, i don't know exactly why, but using static methods of `SubscriptionServiceTest` inside `ClaServiceTest` make`SubscriptionServiceTest` not to be executed by **phpunit** (maybe cause considered as already load ?)

Comment: It's possible, phpunit itself uses static methods such as `setupBeforeClass` to initialize the class for testing so it's possible loading it beforehand is messing up with the actual initialization. You probably need to move those statics to a helper class

Comment: I think it's that, but thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem in the local environment, precisely the same as your case, where only the tests in the Services directory did not run.

To resolve this, I added the following configuration tag to the project's phpunit.xml:

```
<testsuite name="Services">
    <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit/Services</directory>
</testsuite>
```

With this additional configuration, it started considering the Services directory when executing tests.

I suspect it is related to the version of xdebug vs php. Currently, the project is with xdebug-3.1.5 and php7.4, but soon we will migrate to 8.1 and test again if the configuration in the phpunit posted here is still valid.

Doc: https://docs.phpunit.de/en/9.5/organizing-tests.html#organizing-tests-xml-configuration

I hope this helps!